# Maven dependencies in Eclipse subprojects not appearing the Java classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, eclipse-jdt

In Eclipse Java, I have the following situation:

```
Project1
+- Project2
   +- Project3
```

Project1, Project2 and Project3 are regular Java projects that have been created through File > New Java project, then converted to Maven projects through a right-click in Project Explorer > Maven > Convert to Maven. Project1 contains my application entrypoint (static main method). Project1 code calls Project2 code, which in turns calls Project3 code:

```
// Project1
public class Project1Class {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Project2Class.foo();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
// Project2
public class Project2Class {
    public static void foo()
    {
        Project3Class.bar();
    }
}
// Project3
public class Project3Class {
    public static void bar()
    {
       // Use native code here
    }
}
```

Project3 uses a Maven dependency with native library files (DLL files on Windows). Let's call this dependency org.foo.bar/mylibrary:

```
<!-- This dependency needs to load a native library -->
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.foo.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My problem is the following:

When running or debugging Project1, I can see that Project1, Project2 and Project3 'target/classes' folders are in the classpath, as expected, Maven dependencies for Project1 and Project2 also are in the classpath, **but the Maven dependencies of Project3 are missing**. As a result, native libraries cannot be loaded.

If I move the org.foo.bar/mylibrary dependency declaration from Project3 to Project2, then the Maven dependency indeed ends up in the classpath.

I tried with Eclipse 2019-09 and 2020-03, same result.

It seems Eclipse does not add Maven dependencies that reside in *indirect* dependencies.
How can I tell it to add Maven dependencies in the classpath for all dependencies, i.e. both direct and indirect?

EDIT: I added this explicit declaration in Project2's pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Project3</groupId>
        <artifactId>Project3</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and it works. But that makes little sense to me. Considering the other scenario, things do work if I don't add an explicit Maven  declaration between Project1 and Project2. Why? Why do I have to do it between Project2 and Project3 and not between Project1 and Project2 for it to work?

Comment: Maven resolves all transitive (indirect) dependencies. So there must be an error in one of your declarations (it would be good if you add the POMs of all three projects to the question), or you used non-transitive scopes like `test` or `provided`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added an EDIT to my question.

Comment: could you add the full poms please? you may also want to run `mvn help:effective-pom` on each project

Comment: I got it to work and understood the logic. It didn't work because I didn't know Eclipse '.project'-file based dependencies (declared through the Project tab in the Build Path dialog) did not get 'understood' as Maven dependencies, whereas the opposite is true. This is incredible it took me years to understand that! Thank you for your help and support.